# Set a form field value on an SQL variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following in an SQL 2012 stored procedure:

```
V.VoterID IN (SELECT VoterID FROM vts_tbVoterAnswers WHERE AnswerID=@Seed)
```

@Seed is an integer variable in the stored procedure which is supposed to be equal to the value given from an ASP form field named: ddlSeed.

How can I connect the SQL variable with the value of the form field?

EDIT: You are correct @HeavenCore, my question seems too vague, my apologies. Ok this is the form code:

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" MasterPageFile="MsterPageTabs.master" AutoEventWireup="false"%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server"><table summary="maintable" class="TableLayoutContainer">
<tr>
<td class="contentCell" valign="top">
<table summary="exporttable" class="innerText">
<tr>
<td>
<table summary="exporttypetable" class="innerText">
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="CSVOptionPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<tr>
<td width="155">
<br /><strong>
<asp:Literal ID="SeedLabel" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">Seed : </asp:Literal></strong>
</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSeed" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value=""> All </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="32"> Yes </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="31"> No </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList></td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
<asp:Button ID="ExportDataButton" runat="server" Text="Export CSV"></asp:Button></td></tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Basically what it does is allow the user to make a selection from the drop down menu and submit it. Each option in the drop down list holds a value:

[empty] for All
32 for Yes
31 for No

After submitting this the value of the drop down list should become the value of the SQL variable **@Seed** in the following stored procedure:

```
USE [SurveyDB20652]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/// <summary>
/// Return the data needed to export a CSV  file
/// </summary>
*/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[vts_spVoterExportCSVData]
                @SurveyID int,
                @StartDate datetime,
                @EndDate datetime,
                @Seed int
AS

SELECT  SUBSTRING(Q.QuestionText,1,20) as QuestionText,Q.QuestionId,
 AnswerID,SelectionModeId,AnswerTypeId, 
SUBSTRING(Q.QuestionText,1,20)+'...'+' | '+ AnswerText   as ColumnHeader ,
AnswerText,
Q.DisplayOrder QuestionDisplayOrder,
Q.QuestionId,
Q.Alias QuestionAlias,
Q.QuestionIdText QuestionIdText,
A.DisplayOrder AnswerDisplayOrder,
A.AnswerId ,
A.AnswerAlias,Q.ParentQuestionid,
    case when q.parentQuestionId is null then null
    else (select count(*)+1 from vts_tbquestion q1 
             where q1.parentquestionid=q.parentquestionid
             and   q1.questionid<q.questionid
             ) 
    end as roworder,
    case when q.parentQuestionId is null then null
    else (select QuestionText from vts_tbquestion q1 
             where q1.questionid=q.parentquestionid
             ) 
    end as ParentQuestiontext,
    case when q.parentQuestionId is null then null
    else (select QuestionIdText from vts_tbquestion q1 
             where q1.questionid=q.parentquestionid
             ) 
    end as ParentQuestionIdtext,
    case when q.parentQuestionId is null then null
    else (select ALIAS from vts_tbquestion q1 
             where q1.questionid=q.parentquestionid
             ) 
    end as ParentQuestionAliastext,
A.AnswerIDText AnswerIdText
 FROM vts_tbQuestion Q
INNER JOIN vts_tbAnswer A
    ON A.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID
WHERE 
    SurveyID = @SurveyID  
ORDER BY Q.DisplayOrder, Q.QuestionID, A.DisplayOrder

SELECT
    V.VoterID,
    V.VoteDate,
    V.StartDate,
    V.IPSource,
    V.ContextUserName as username,
    (SELECT sum(ScorePoint) FROM vts_tbVoter 
        INNER JOIN vts_tbVoterAnswers
            ON vts_tbVoterAnswers.VoterID = vts_tbVoter.VoterID
        INNER JOIN vts_tbAnswer
            ON vts_tbAnswer.AnswerID = vts_tbVoterAnswers.AnswerID
        WHERE vts_tbVoter.VoterID = V.VoterID) AS Score
    FROM vts_tbVoter V
    WHERE 
        V.SurveyID = @SurveyID AND
        V.Validated <> 0 AND
        DATEDIFF (d,@startDate,V.VoteDate) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF (d,@endDate,V.VoteDate) <= 0 AND
        V.VoterID IN (SELECT VoterID FROM vts_tbVoterAnswers WHERE AnswerID=@Seed)
    ORDER BY V.VoterID DESC

SELECT
    V.VoterID,
    VA.AnswerID,
    SectionNumber,
    VA.AnswerText,
    AnswerTypeId,
    SelectionModeId,
    Q.QuestionId,
    A.AnswerText AnswerAnswerText,
    A.DisplayOrder AnswerDisplayOrder,
A.AnswerAlias,
A.AnswerIDText AnswerIdAlias
FROM vts_tbVoterAnswers VA
INNER JOIN vts_tbVoter V
    ON V.VoterID = VA.VoterID
INNER JOIN vts_tbAnswer A
    ON VA.AnswerId=A.AnswerId
INNER JOIN vts_tbQuestion Q
     ON A.QuestionId=Q.QuestionId
WHERE 
    V.SurveyID = @SurveyID AND
    V.Validated <> 0 AND
    DATEDIFF (d,@startDate,V.VoteDate) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF (d,@endDate,V.VoteDate) <= 0 AND
    V.VoterID IN (SELECT VoterID FROM vts_tbVoterAnswers WHERE AnswerID=@Seed)


ORDER BY V.VoterID DESC
```

The above procedure basically works as a filter. It filters out all database entries that do not have a VoterID entry in the vts_tbVoterAnswers table, which has a corresponding AnswerID entry equal to the value of @Seed (which can be either '' or 32 or 31)

So if in the drop down list:
I select All, then the @Seed='' : will select all entries in the table vts_tbVoterAnswers
If I select Yes, then @Seed='32': will filter out VoterID 120 and all its entries
If I select No, then @Seed='31' : will filter out VoterID 109 and all its entries

vts_tbVoterAnswers table looks like this:

```
VoterID | AnswerID | SectionNumber | AnswerText

109     | 3        | 0             | 12/03/2000

109     | 23       | 0             | NULL

109     | 32       | 0             | NULL

120     | 3        | 0             | 26/11/1979

120     | 23       | 0             | NULL

120     | 31       | 0             | NULL
```

So my problem is how to connect the @Seer SQL variable with the value given by the drop down list.. :)

I hope this explanation is better than my previous one. :)

Comment: You're using ASP.net with c# - you tagged your question with asp-classic - these are very different! I'll revise my answer later to .net (unless someone beats me to it - too busy at the moment)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I thought I tagged it asp.NET, but seems like accidentally I clicked wrong. Apologies for that. And thank you.

Comment: Are you using .net data binding, data sources and all that jazz or is your database stuff written manually in ado.net?

Comment: I am not really sure. The original code isn't mine to be honest and Im not familiar to ASP.NET. Im just trying to modify the current one to my needs. The web application basically is an opensource web application called: Survey Project 2.0. The source code is online here: http://survey.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60534ac17f37  .  You may find the code in: SurveyWAP>>NSurveyAdmin>>ExportData.aspx . Im sorry I can't provide any other more useful info.

Comment: The app is using .net data binding

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague,

Assuming @Seed is a paramater on your proc.
Assuming your proc is called usp_GetVotes

You would call the proc from ASP passing the form value to the paramater:

```
'#### Make sure you have adovbs.inc

'#### Ready objects
Set db = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
set dbc = CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 

'#### Connect to SQL
db.Open "YourConnectionString"

'#### Build & Execute Command
With dbc
    .ActiveConnection = db
    .CommandText = "vts_spVoterExportCSVData" 
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Seed", adInt, adParamInput, , request.form("ddlSeed"))
    set rs = .Execute 
End With
```

Or, if you want to be very quick and dirty:

```
set rs = db.execute("EXEC vts_spVoterExportCSVData @Seed = " & replace(request.form("ddlSeed"),"'","''"))
```

**Edit 1: C# version for your clarified question:**

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString);
SqlCommand dbc = new SqlCommand("vts_spVoterExportCSVData", db);
dbc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter Seed = dbc.Parameters.Add("@Seed", SqlDbType.Int);
Seed.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
Seed.Value = request.form("ddlSeed");
db.Open();

SqlDataReader Results = dbc.ExecuteReader();

while (Results.Read())  {
    //Results["VoterID"].ToString();
    //Results["AnswerID"].ToString();
    //Results["SectionNumber"].ToString();
    //Results["AnswerText"].ToString();
};

Results.Close();
```

Comment: I tried the "quick & dirty solution" and I got this error: "Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'set' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" . Seems like 'set' is not compiled as a type properly. Am I missing something? (Note: All this page is in C# not VB btw)

Comment: I did a bit of reading and came up with this: <% 
Dim SQLCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection;
SQLCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=[server];User ID=[username];Password=[pass];";
SQLCon.Open();
SQLCmd.CommandText = "vts_spVoterExportCSVData";
SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SQLCmd.Connection = SQLCon;
SQLCmd.Parameters.Execute("EXEC vts_spVoterExportCSVData @Seed = " & Replace(Request.Form["ddlSeed"],"'","''"));       
%> but I get a "Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected." But where should I add the semi-column?

Comment: Ok I think the error described above appears cause the Language that it compiles the page with is C#. So this means I will have to re-write the above in C#, or is there a way to make that injected code work?

Comment: @user1682404 "Dim " etc is vb.net - your need c# version, see Edit 1 on my answer for the c# version. Also, your not using parameters in that VB version which opens you up to SQL injection etc, the C# version i have posted uses a parameterised command object - much safer.

Comment: Thank you for the help HeavenCore. I really appreciate it! I tested your code and it returned me an error: Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected ...And highlights Line: 207.  
Line 205:<%
Line 206:@Code
Line 207:SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("MyCnnectionstring);
Line 208:SqlCommand dbc = new SqlCommand("vts_spVoterExportCSVData", db);
Line 209:dbc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: looks like the error is on line 207 - something to do with your connection string? missing quotes perhaps?

Comment: I simply replaced the connection string here on the site. Else on the actual code its like: "Server=servername;Database=databasename;User ID=username;Password=password"

Comment: Ok, I discovered I had to put: <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
and modified the code at the request.form like this: Seed.Value = Request.Form["ddlSeed"]; Now I get: Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
Source Error:
Line 214:Seed.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
Line 215:Seed.Value = Request.Form["ddlSeed"];
Line 216:db.Open();
Line 217:
Line 218:SqlDataReader Results = dbc.ExecuteReader();
Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\aristotelis\NSurveyAdmin\ExportData.aspx   Line: 216